# strip last comma from get_the_category

Tags: categories

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    echo $category->cat_name . ', ';

}
```

So I'm echoing it like this because I don't want the categories to appear as hyperlinks, I just want the cat names.

The problem is I can't get rid of the last separator so it ends up like : category, category, category,

I tried 'stripping' it (php seriously confuses me small design mind)

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    echo $category->cat_name . ', ';
    echo rtrim($category, ", ");
}
```

That didn't trim it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this issue. You need a clean array of category names for both, so let’s start with that:

```
$cat_names = wp_list_pluck( get_the_category(), 'cat_name');
```

`$cat_names` is now an array with just the names:

```
Array
(
    [0] => aciform
    [1] => Cat A
    [2] => Cat B
    [3] => Cat C
    [4] => sub
)
```

Now you can use the simple way:

```
echo join( ', ', $cat_names );
```

Result: *aciform, Cat A, Cat B, Cat C, sub*

But my recommendation is to use the grammatically correct list, use `wp_sprintf_l()`:

```
echo wp_sprintf_l( '%l', $cat_names );
```

Result: *aciform, Cat A, Cat B, Cat C, and sub*

`wp_sprintf_l()` will use a localized separator for the last two items, so in a German site this would output: *aciform, Cat A, Cat B, Cat C und sub*.

And you don’t even have to care about the correct translation – the proper separator is part of the regular language files.

Comment: Yeah, that's fantastic toscho, thanks!
I prefer the second one, though it's not quite grammatically correct if it lists more than 3 categories. 
Since it says category, category, and category
the last comma in that sentence shouldn't really be there.

Comment: @andy That’s a [Serial comma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma) and quite correct. You can filter `'between_last_two'` and change it if you want.

Answer (score 2):

There's another way to do this using CSS and a pseudo selector to add the commas. You would just need to wrap each category in an HTML tag eg:

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {
    echo '<span class="category">' . $category->cat_name . '<span>';
}
```

And then with CSS:

```
.category:not(:last-child)::after {
    content: ",";
}
```

EDIT: This solution will only work in browsers that support these pseudo selectors (IE 9 and up)

Comment: This would however fail on browsers that does not support the pseudo classes